# Out of Universe, was Romulan bridge design influenced by The TARDIS?

Tags: star-trek, doctor-who, star-trek-tos, romulan

As a fan of both franchises, something has long nagged at me. Looking at the bridges of several Romulan vessels, I can't help but notice a common design element: a central column which some or all of the bridge officers face inward toward:

[image: Balance of Terror]

[image: Enterprise: Romulan Drone Ship]

Once I was introduced to Doctor Who, this naturally came to mind once I saw The TARDIS console:

[image: 80's TARDIS console]

My question is, out of universe, was the Romulan design cribbed from Doctor Who? Do they both draw from some real-world design? Is it total coincidence?

Comment: I think freestanding consoles were common enough when I was young, though I suppose my memories mostly represent just my father's workplace.  I think this may have been because technical equipment tended to be heavy and hence difficult to move, but also needed frequent repair, so you had to have easy access to the back.

Comment: This strikes me as less freestanding than 4-5 consoles joined by their backs.

Comment: Sure, but the point is that the ST designers (presumably older than I am, since I was still in my late teens when STNG came out) had almost certainly been exposed to real-world technical equipment located in the middle of the room.  So if it is a coincidence it's a quite unremarkable one, bordering on not qualifying as a coincidence at all, any more than you would call it a coincidence that the TARDIS bridge and the Enterprise bridge both have doors. :-)

Comment: The 1956 movie "Forbidden Planet" also had a central "astrogator" that various members of the crew would gather around, see some of the images on [this page](http://alchetron.com/Forbidden-Planet-18918-W), such as [this one](http://www.cinemablend.com/images/news/18557/_1273723211.jpg) and [this one](http://fitheach.co.uk/images/movies/forbidden-planet/forbidden-planet-commander-adams).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two Romulan examples remind me of a [submarine control room](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Skipjack_control_room.svg). Which would be very fitting considering the Romulan cloaking devices.

Tertiary sources quote *[The Star Trek Compendium](http://www.brettzimmerman.ca/Ellipses.pdf)*:

> Many “Star Trek” episodes were written from an initial inspiration, a
>   preexisting literary  or  motion  picture  concept  expressed  in 
>   terms  of  the  world  of  tomorrow.  Usually,  those  ideas were
>   reworked so  thoroughly it was difficult to spot the original
>   inspiration.  This  segment  is  a  notable  exception.  Its 
>   dramatic  situations  are  drawn  largely  from  two  motion  pictures
>   about  submarine  warfare,  Run  Silent, Run  Deep and  The  Enemy 
>   Below .  “Balance of Terror” is a war movie translated into science
>   fiction terms: a confrontation  between a “surface vessel” (the 
>   Enterprise ) and a “submarine” (the invisible Romulan  ship). **The
>
>   cramped quarters of the Romulan bridge suggest a submarine-type  environment:  there  is   even  a  monitor  device that  resembles  a  periscope**  (the  Enterprise chapel is just a  redress of the transporter room set).

Comment: @N_Soong, the OP asked "Do they both draw from some real-world design?" I reminded him of a real-world design precedent.

Comment: Addition of the source greatly improve it - good find